# sudoing when logged in as root

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, root

```
sudo -s
//entry of password
//logged in as root
sudo -s
//no password required
sudo -s
exit
//still logged in as root
exit
exit
//finally logged out of root
```

I don't understand why this happens. If I type `exit` at the command line, while being logged in as the root user, I should be logged out.

Comment: Each `sudo -s` starts a new subshell.

Answer (score 4):

The -s flag for sudo creates a new shell, so every time you type sudo -s you are creating new shells, and then exiting back up to the top.